# Asking for project change post maternity leave

Tags: career-development, new-job

In less than a month I will return from maternity leave. I had been working in a project prior to leaving for maternity leave but I am now looking for a change in project due to certain concerns with my previous project.

- Monotonous work that does not give me career growth and does not enhance my skillsets.
- additional project work during night (apart from work during the day) which I am not preferring now as I have to look after the baby
- tight schedule in project which involves chasing for daily targets working in pressurized mode. This would again cause extension of working hours at office but I prefer leaving early during the initial days after returning back from maternity leave.

How do I let my manager know about these concerns and my willingness for a new project?

Comment: In essence you want better working conditions, maternity leave or not. Talk to your boss. Prepare to be told no, though.-

Answer (score 5):

The best way to approach this with you manager would be to figure out how to make it a win for your manager and the company.

For each concern you have, find a reason why working on a different project would benefit the company.  This way, you can set up a win-win.  A company is going to be much more accommodating to you if you can demonstrate a willingness to compromise.  The very fact that the companies needs are being considered will show that you're a "team player".  Otherwise, it's going to look to some as if you're using your position to dodge work.  whether or not that is fair, or is the case, that's how it will be perceived.

Coming back from any leave with a list of demands does not put a person in a good light.  Frame any schedule changes or shifting of your work or changing projects as being of benefit to the company.  You will get much farther that way.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that the answer really has much to do with the fact that you will be returning from maternity leave. If you're back from leave, you need to be back, and not request to be put on a different project for this sole reason.

If you truly have issues with what were working on previously, you can express that in ways that you normally would.

You should commit to finishing whatever project you are currently working on, but you can also talk to your manager about the possibility of working on something new in the future.

You should phrase this request in a way that expresses your interest in a new project in a positive manner, something that will be mutually beneficial for you and your employer, as @Richard U mentioned.